# CSS transition on variable height span & header when containing div mouseovered

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Current example: DELETED LINK

An `h2` overlays the foot of an image and is permanently visible. When the cursor hovers over the image the `span` text beneath the `h2` moves over the image and pushes the `h2` up with it. That currently works, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to add an ease transition as the extra text comes into view on hover. The `h2` and `span` are both contained in `div.img_txt` so maybe that's the key?

I can get the transition on the text to work but it doesn't push the `h2` up. The main problem seems to be it won't be a fixed height that I want the text to move up, as it could be anything between 1 to 4 lines. The `h2` could also go over 1 or more lines.

This is the code that works without any transition effect:

**HTML**

```
<div class="rimg1">
  <a href=""><div class="img_txt"><h2>Apples the most attractive fruit</h2><span>Apples pip other fruits as most appeeling for core values</span></div><img src="graphics/apple-tree.jpg" width="304" height="220" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.rimg1{
  float: left;
  width: 284px;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
}

div.rimg1 span{
  color: #fff; 
  font-size: 0.9em; 
  position: absolute; 
  visibility: hidden; 
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  /* cross-browser transition CSS removed for ease of viewing */
}

div.rimg1:hover span{
  position: relative; 
  bottom: 0; 
  visibility: visible;
}

div.img_txt{
  width: 284px; 
  background: rgba(51,51,51,0.80); 
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; 
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0; 
  z-index: 9; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The various positioning attributes above are for the layout of the overall page, which has a number of images at different sizes.

In the current code the only change that would be effective with the transition is the visibility, as I don't think a change from absolute to relative positioning would have an effect if there's no distance value added?

Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: in order to see transition working you need to use rule where values are numbers, so it calculates steps. visible/hidden just jumps from a valu to the other, there's no possible ways to say:visible/hidden 50%, unless you use opacity:0 & 1;.

Comment: Yes, so either animate the opacity or the height from 0px to auto - then your element will fade/resize accordingly.

Comment: @Chen Thanks both - I knew numbers were needed, I just didn't explain it very well. height:auto didn't work on it's own, but I added a min and max-height as per this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5611482/1951960